# How to disable context menuitem when it is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

In my WPF project, I have a context menu. When clicking the context menu item, I should make that item disabled from the view model.

```
var cm = new ContextMenu();    
var disableItem= new MenuItem
{
    Header = "Disable",
    Command = new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {                        
        // here we need to disable this menu item. 
    })
};    
cm.Items.Add(disableItem);
```

`cm` is bound to the xaml. How can I achieve this?

**Tried the following code but still not working can someone help what is wrong here?**

```
private ContextMenu CreateContextMenu()
{
  var cm = new ContextMenu();
  var mItemDisable = new MenuItem{
        Header = "Dynamic Disable",
        Command = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        { IsContextItemEnabled = false; })};

  var binding = new Binding();
  binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
  binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
  binding.Source = IsContextItemEnabled;
  mItemDisable.SetBinding(MenuItem.IsEnabledProperty, binding);
  cm.Items.Add(mItemDisable);
  return cm;
}

private bool _isContextItemEnabled = true;
private bool IsContextItemEnabled
{
   get { return _isContextItemEnabled; }
   set
     {
      _isContextItemEnabled = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("IsContextItemEnabled");
     }
 }
```

Comment: this.IsEnabled = false; (?)

Comment: `this` doesn't give the `MenuItem` remember we are in the delegate method.

Comment: Can you use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654427.aspx) that lets you supply a `CanExecute` func?

Comment: This solution(`CanExecute` func): will not allow the command to execute; but doesn't disable the menuitem.

Comment: Add `IsMyCommandEnabled` flag to your VM, return it in `CanExecute` function and change its value in `Execute` delegate.

Comment: To go a little further, if you're using [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can centrally enable and disable any function, because the UI tests `CanExecute` (an arbitrary function you write to return a `bool`) for each command. Very handy.

Comment: I have tried it but that doesn't change the style of the menu item to "Disabled".

Answer (score 0):

This may be oversimplifying things, but here's code that works - maybe not the most elegant, but functional.

Have your window class keep a member variable reference to the MenuItem `MenuItem m_disableItem = null;`

Then, have it implement a method to disable the MenuItem:

```
void DisableItem()
{
    m_disableItem.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Finally, have the delegate call that method:

```
var cm = new ContextMenu();
// Keep the menuItem as a member variable
m_disableItem = new MenuItem
{
    Header = "Disable",
    Command = new DelegateCommand((parameter) => this.DisableItem())
};
cm.Items.Add(m_disableItem);
```

**Edit:**
I'm not sure I agree with the pattern being applied here, but you could make use of the `MenuItem's` `CommandParameter` to return the sending `MenuItem` to the `DelegateCommand`:

```
var cm = new ContextMenu();
var disableItem = new MenuItem
{
    Header = "Disable",
    Command = new DelegateCommand<MenuItem>((parameter) =>
        {
            parameter.IsEnabled = false;
        })
};
disableItem.CommandParameter = disableItem;
cm.Items.Add(disableItem);
this.ContextMenu = cm;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In this I have to maintain the reference but I want some thing with out maintaining the reference to the menuitem